# Filter mongodb from custom query objects as input

Tags: mongodb, filter

I am trying to filter my search results by id and version from a list of input. If the version is not provided, then get the latest for that ID. the below query works when I have both id and version. However, for id:2, I need only the latest to be returned.

```
db.mycollection.find({
$or: [
    {
        id: 1,
        version: 1
    },
    {
        id : 1,
        version: 2
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        version: {$max: "$version"} // get the latest version if not provided
    }
]})
```

I get the below error

```
{
"message" : "unknown operator: $max",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue",
"name" : "MongoError"}
```

Comment: Tried the below query
```db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
    {
        id: 1,
        version: 1
    },
    {
        id : 1,
        version: 2
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        version: "$version"
    }]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id : "$id", 
            "version": {"$max": "$version"}
        }
    }
    ])```
Got the output as only one doc

`
{
 "_id" : 1,
 "version" : 2
}
`

Comment: I posted an answer. Please tell me if the result is the expected one or is it something else.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I’m expecting three documents in result. I will try the below one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation query using facets can get documents for the two different conditions:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate( [
  { $facet: {
     with_version: [
          { $match: { $or: [ { id: 1, version: 1 }, { id: 3, version: 2 } ] } },
     ],
     without_version: [
          { $match: { id: 2 } },
          { $sort: { version: -1 } },
          { $limit: 1 },
     ],
  } },
  { $project: { docs: { $concatArrays: [ "$with_version", "$without_version" ] } } },
  { $unwind: "$docs" },
  { $project: { _id: "$docs._id", id: "$docs.id", version: "$docs.version" } },
] )
```

Using the following documents as input:

```
{ "_id" : "a", "id" : 1, "version" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "b", "id" : 2, "version" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "c", "id" : 3, "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "d", "id" : 2, "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "e", "id" : 4, "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "f", "id" : 3, "version" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "g", "id" : 3, "version" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "h", "id" : 2, "version" : 0 }
```

The result shows the matching documents for `{ id: 1, version: 1 }`, `{ id: 3, version: 2 }`, and the maximum version number for `id: 2`.

```
{ "_id" : "a", "id" : 1, "version" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "c", "id" : 3, "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "d", "id" : 2, "version" : 2 }
```

Comment: Will this support multiple ids in the `without_version` query? This returns multiple docs on 2 if 5 and 7 are not found.

`db.myCollection.aggregate([{$facet:{with_version: [{ $match: { $or: [{ "id": 1, "version": 1 }, { "id": 3, "version": 2 }] } },],without_version: [{ $match: { "id": { $in: [2,5,7] } } },{ $sort: { "version": -1 } },{ $limit: 3 }],}},
    { $project: { docs: { $concatArrays: ["$with_version", "$without_version"] } } },
    { $unwind: "$docs" }
    { $project: { _id: "$docs._id", id: "$docs.id", version: "$docs.version" } }
])
`

Comment: This worked. Thanks.. 
```db.myCollection.aggregate([{$facet: {with_version: [{ $match: { $or: [{ "id": 1, "version": 1 }, { "id": 3, "version": 2 }] } },],
       without_version: [
                { $match: { "id": { $in: [2, 5, 7] } } },
                { $sort: { "version": -1 } },
                { $group: { _id: { "uniqueId": "$id" }, "doc": { "$first": "$$CURRENT" } } },
                { $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$doc" } }
            ],
        }
    },
    { $project: { docs: { $concatArrays: ["$with_version", "$without_version"] } } },
    { $unwind: "$docs" }
])```